# 2 Routers for PPPoE and NAT 5 Public IP

Tags: routing, router, nat, wan, route-server

My ISP have provided me with 5 Public IPs. I tried to NAT these 5 IPs to our local server by using this setup. The primary router will be setup for the internet connection while the one-to-one NAT of the 5 IPs will run on the Secondary Router.

Here my setup:

**Primary router (PPPoE connection)**

WAN IP: 172.217.22.15 (sample)

LAN IP: 192.168.2.1/24

**Secondary router (Static IP & NAT)**

WAN IP: 172.217.22.16/29

Default gateway: 172.217.22.15

LAN IP: 192.168.3.1/24

Static route: 192.168.7.0 255.255.255.0 172.217.22.15

**Physical connection:**
The primary router's LAN interface connected to the WAN interface of the secondary router.

The primary router able to get connected to the internet but not the secondary router thus the NAT also failed. From the secondary router, I failed to ping the primary router WAN IP.

Please help, it almost a year I tried to figure out the connection.

Comment: Sorry, consumer-grade hardware is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

Answer (score 1):

> The primary router's LAN interface connected to the WAN interface of the secondary router.

That won't work. The primary router's LAN subnet doesn't match the secondary router's WAN IP. The public WAN subnet is 'on link' on the PPPoE connection - the public gateway is on the far side and all your usable, public addresses are on your, the primary router's side.

Instead, define all your usable WAN IPs on the primary router and then port forward/destination NAT them to private IP addresses as required.

Change the secondary router's WAN IP address to be part of the primary's LAN subnet. Also, you'll need to add a static route on the primary router to 192.168.3.1/24 via that secondary router's 'WAN' interface IP. Of course, you don't NAT on the secondary router.

Comment: @Renivle, those consumer-grade devices are off-topic here.